# HTML - 'onclick' confirm function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

Hello fellow stack overflowers.

Pretty much, in my current project I want to have a menu that shows all clients and the option to delete them; when you click delete, I want it to say something like 'Are you sure you want to delete this client??'. My menu/table is represented in php tags within my html file. Before actually implementing it into my table, I wanted to try it out to make sure it works. I got it to work in html but when I tried it in php it wouldn't?? As you can see I tried different quotation marks as when I did it with " and ' I kept getting errors. I'm probably just being a little scrub but I'm not sure how to do it. Could somebody help me please (see code below).

Many thanks, Jack.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
View Clients
</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">test</a>

<?php

echo "<a href='http://google.com' onclick='return confirm(`Are you sure?`)'>test</a>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IGNORE, my sixth form has an outdated browser. I just tried it on firefox and it worked fine...

Comment: 1) why echo at all? 2)  change `'Are you sure'` to `\'Are you sure\'` - this is the case in all browsers

Comment: Absolutely positively never EVER use `a[href]` to perform data-changing actions on the server. ESPECIALLY not deletion. I cannot emphasize this enough. I try, but this is all I can do: ***DON'T DO IT!***

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol well I need to link to my DeleteClient.php so how else am I supposed to get there???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://google.com\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">test</a>";
```

Comment: thank you, I'm just about to have lunch and then I have a free period, so I'll try it then and let you know how it goes

Comment: @Jack ok and accept the answer if it is working for you:) thanks

Comment: No worries, ignore my prevous comments (if you saw them), got it to work.

Comment: When an answer just says *Try this...*,  and drops in code, it really doesn't explain why code was originally failing. Please give an explanation so that future readers will understand what needed to be done. You know, and I know, but let's think about the people who don't know the *reason* why and have less experience than you and I. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To re-iterate what I have said in my comment NEVER use `a[href]` to do anything that modifies or deletes data from your server. For an extreme example of why not, [check out this article](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/08/08/hey-you-deleted-my-files/)

> We got a rather strongly worded message the other day from a Webmaster who was threatening legal action because our crawler deleted a bunch of files from his site.  The news that our crawler is capable of deleting files was quite a surprise to us.  Like other crawlers, ours just downloads HTML files, extracts links, and then visits those links.  There is no “delete a file” logic in there.  But if the crawler stumbles upon a link whose action is to delete a file, then visiting that link will indeed delete the file.

So what can you do instead?

The most basic way would be to use a `<form>` instead. Crawlers do not submit forms, and they are also slightly better to defend against CSRF attacks. In this case, you would have something like:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post"
  onSubmit="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="delete_me" />
    <button type="submit">Delete!</button>
</form>
```

However, this really shouldn't be considered sufficient. So let me show you what I have implemented on my own site to confirm a potentially-devastating-if-done-by-accident deletion:

1. Click the delete button.
2. Receive a pop-up asking if you want to delete it.
3. Send an AJAX request to the server, preparing the deletion action. Server responds with a one-time unique key and saves it in `$_SESSION`.
4. Give the user a second confirmation, making damn sure they understand what they are about to do if they continue.
5. If the user still wants to delete it, send the final deletion request with the one-time unique key that was received in Step 3.

This is a very safe and secure way to ensure that deletion can only happen if the user actually wants to delete it. It is immune to CSRF because of its multi-step nature and thanks to the use of the one-time key.

You may wish to delete Step 2 from the list above - in my particular case having two confirmation pop-ups is a really good idea to prevent accidental mis-haps, but realistically in most situations you only need one, after having gotten the one-time key.

The exact implementation will be up to you, but it is quite simple to do - just make sure that you properly verify the one-time key.

Comment: Alternative: `<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('are you sure')) location.replace('delete.php?id=bla');">Delete</a>`

Comment: @mplungjan That solves the problem of crawlers, but it's wide open to CSRF.

Comment: If the POST is the improvement you think of, then `<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('are you sure')) $.post('delete.php',{id:'bla'});">Delete</a>` should be better too, no?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, that would work, although at that point you might as well have a `<button>` ;)

Comment: Ah yes, button or link - button is purer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using backticks instead of quotes in your `onclick()` call -

```
echo '<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">test</a>';
```

You should escape any quotes that aren't working as you would expecting.

Comment: When I tried it with normal quotes I would get a syntax error; that's why I had to use backticks

Comment: Backticks are typically reserved for SQL statements and should never be used as replacements for quotes. Glad this helped!